# How to split string using regexp in ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I need to split my string based on Boolean operators.

Now i'm using

`.split(/(.+?)((?: AND | OR | NOT ))/).reject(&:empty?).reject(&:blank?)`

In this method it did not split if the string starts with Boolean operators.

Tested strings

1. a AND b
2. AND b

returned output

1. ["a","AND","b"]
2. ["AND b"]

what am i missed.

Comment: Can you explain why?

Comment: you don't convert strings, you can only create different strings.  your question isn't making sense.

Comment: Do you mean you want: `['County', 'blue', 'of', 'origin']`?

Comment: I am curious on why the limitation on not using split?  Seems odd to remove a tool which is well suited to the task.

Comment: Is this an exercise?  It may be that your instructor wants to test your looping logic?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your could use `scan`:

```
str.scan(/\w+/)
#=> ["Country", "blue", "of", "origin"]
```

This will work not only with commas, but any non-numeric, non-letter character (except `_`).

**UPDATE**

Looking closely at your desired output, it seems that you want to keep the spaces between commas:

> I want a desired output like this.
>
> > [Country ,blue,of, origin]

If so, use this instead:

```
str.scan(/[\w\s]+/)
#=> ["Country ", "blue", "of", " origin"]
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution convert string to array without split

```
str = "Country ,blue,of, origin"

 Array(str.chars.join(""))
```